# XML Deserialization with "mixed" type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to consume XML from a web service. I initially started using LINQ to XML but after learning about serialization/deserialization I decided I would instead just try to deserialize the XML.

Although I haven't yet written the deserialization code, I've realised that due to how the web service works, I can't always know the actual type being returned for certain elements.

For example consider this XML (http://api.wunderground.com/api/d36f54198ebbb48c/conditions/q/England/London.xml)

```
<dewpoint_string>52 F (11 C)</dewpoint_string> 
<dewpoint_f>52</dewpoint_f>   
<dewpoint_c>11</dewpoint_c>    
<heat_index_string>NA</heat_index_string>
<heat_index_f>NA</heat_index_f>
<heat_index_c>NA</heat_index_c>
```

Now, normally provided that all the data is available then elements such as "heat_index_f" would be a decimal/double. However when certain parts of the data is not available the service will instead have the string value of "NA" in the element. I am deserializing to an object, that has properties for each element. EG: `string HeatIndexString; double HeatIndexF;` Obviously, if the service returns with the string NA then I will get a runtime exception of trying to convert "NA" to a double.

How should I tackle this problem? Is there some type of attribute I can tell the deserializer to somehow work with these "mixed" types? How do other developers deal with situations like this?

Comment: Is there any *reason* why you want to use XML serialization for this rather than doing it with LINQ to XML? I suspect that LINQ to XML would be considerably simpler.

Comment: XML serialization can also be a little fragile.  Minor changes to the XML that are insignificant may very well throw run time errors when de-serializing

Comment: declare `HeatIndexF` as string :) you can *"TryParse"* whenever you need its value as double.